# Jensen inequality on square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, jensen-inequality

For a concave function $f$, Jensen inequality states that

$$
f(ax+by) \geq af(x) + bf(y)
$$

Now, $\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function, hence by Jensen inequality

$$
\sqrt{x+y} \geq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}
$$

But by elementary algebra, we know

$$
(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2 = x + y + 2\sqrt{xy}
$$
and hence
$$
\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \geq \sqrt{x + y}
$$

Why I get contradictory results ?

Comment: which inequality do you use?

Comment: It is required that $a+b=1$, isn't it?

Comment: yes this is the Point!

Comment: @C.Falcon I think, that is the catch

Comment: For completeness, Jensen's inequality gives $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} y} \ge \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{y}$ and therefore, combining this with your other bound, we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}) \le \sqrt{x + y} \le \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comments, you missed an important part of the definition of concavity (and so Jensen's inequality): If $\lambda \in [0,1]$ then 
$$
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)
$$
where you have taken $a=\lambda$, $b=1-\lambda$.

It may help to think of what this means geometrically: The points on the line between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ (in the plane where $f$ is graphed), call one of them $(p_1,p_2)$ are smaller than the points on the graph, $(p_1,f(p_1))$.

I encourage you to draw the picture.