# For which values of a is this mapping a metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry, metric-spaces

The task is: Find all values of parameter $a \in (0, \infty)$ such that $d(x,y)= |arctan(x-y)|^a $ defines a metric on $\mathbb{R}$. All properites of metric are satisfied, the only problem is triangle inequality. I wasn't sure if I should prove that it holds or find a counterexample so that it doesn't  hold, so I tried both but didn't manage to prove anything. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: The function needs to be concave. If there's a convexity, the triangle inequality fails in that region. I think the answer should be $a\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Could you please give some more explanation? Should I use the definition of concave function to prove or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t):=|\arctan(t)|$. You need to prove two things:

(i) $f(s+t)\le f(s)+f(t)$. (You can use the $\tan$ sum formula for this.) Then it follows that for $a\le1$, $$f(s+t)^a\le(f(s)+f(t))^a\le f(s)^a+f(t)^a$$ (the second inequality by the concavity of $x^a$, i.e., $(x+y)^a\le x^a+y^a$.)

(ii) Near to $t=0$, $f(t)^a=|t^a-\frac{a}{3}t^{a+2}+\cdots|\approx |t|^a$, which is convex for $a>1$. So, pick two points close to zero, such that $|t_1+t_1|^a>|t_1|^a+|t_2|^a$. Then $$f(t_1+t_2)^a\ge|t_1+t_2|^a-\epsilon>|t_1|^a+|t_2|^a+\epsilon\ge f(t_1)^a+f(t_2)^a$$ so the triangle inequality fails for $x,y,z$ small, $$|\arctan(x-z)|^a>|\arctan(x-y)|^a+|\arctan(y-z)|^a$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question: when proving  $f(s+t)\leq f(s)+f(t) $, what will I do with absolute values, will I consider all cases depending on sign of $arctan$? For example if $arctan(s), arctan(t)> 0 $ i.e. $s,t> 0$ we get: $ s +t \leq \frac{s+t} { 1-s t}$, which is true for $ s t \leq 1$, otherwise it is false.

Comment: And also, relating to  the inequality  $ (x+y)^a≤x^a+y^a$, where can I find it in literature, is it some kind of Jensen's inequality?

Comment: Yes and yes. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697664/jensen-inequality-on-square-root